# Show a picture when mousemove over a text with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

do you know any tutorial or script that shows a picture when mousemove over a html text?

Comment: When you say "mousemove", do you mean when the pointer hovers over the text? Or do you actually mean only display the image while the mouse is moving? Can you offer any more specifics?

Comment: and when you mean show a picture, you mean remove the text and then show a pictute or show a picture somewhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic example using jQuery would be something like this:

CSS

```
#myImage {
    display:none;
}​
```

HTML

```
<span class='pictureTrigger'>some text</span>

<img id='myImage' src='/path/to/image' />​
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {  // Makes sure DOM loads before code is run

    $('.pictureTrigger').hover(   // Assign event handlers for mouseenter/mouseleave

        function() { $('#myImage').show(); },  // Find myImage and show it on mouseenter
        function() { $('#myImage').hide(); }   // Find myImage and hide it on mouseleave
    );

});
```

​It's hard to give a better answer without more specifics in the question.

The basic idea is that the text is contained in a `span`, which has a class called `pictureTrigger`. Could be named anything, though.

A hover event (which is actually shorthand for two events, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`) is added to all elements with the `pictureTrigger` class.

The two functions represent the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events respectively. The event handler functions find the `img` with the ID `myImage`, and show/hide it.

---

**Relevant jQuery docs:**

- `.show()` - http://api.jquery.com/show/
- `.hide()` - http://api.jquery.com/hide/
- `.hover()` - http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score -1):

Google for tooltip plugin. There's a lot of them.